# Displaying multiple information in messagebox from listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a program that is having me input information about a boat and add that information to a listbox.  the only thing that will show up in the listbox is the name of the boat.  I need to know how to display all the information from the other textboxes such as length, sail size, and engines in a messagebox. Any help is appreciated.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ArrayList Home;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Home = new ArrayList();

    }

    private void btnAddApartment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //instantiate appartment and add it to arraylist
        try
        {
            Apartment anApartment = new Apartment(txtID.Text, txtAddress.Text, int.Parse(txtYearBuilt.Text), int.Parse(txtBedrooms.Text),
                double.Parse(txtSquareFootage.Text), double.Parse(txtPrice.Text), txtFurnished.Text);
            Home.Add(anApartment);
            ClearText(this);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Make sure you entered everything correctly!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }            

    }

    private void btnAddHouse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try 
        {
            House aHouse=new House(txtID.Text, txtAddress.Text, int.Parse(txtYearBuilt.Text), int.Parse(txtBedrooms.Text),
                double.Parse(txtSquareFootage.Text), double.Parse(txtPrice.Text),int.Parse(txtGarageCapacity.Text));
            Home.Add(aHouse);
            AddHouseToListBox();
            ClearText(this);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Make sure you entered everything correctly!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }

    private void ClearText(Control controls)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls.Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)control).Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddHouseToListBox()
    {
        lstHouse.Items.Clear();
        foreach (House person in Home)
        {
            lstHouse.Items.Add(person.GetAddress());
        }
    }

    private void AddApartmentToListBox()
    {
        lstApartment.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Apartment persons in Home)
        {
            lstApartment.Items.Add(persons.GetAddress());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you currently have. It sounds like you need to fill the ListBoxItem fully, but the code is needed to be sure

Comment: Wow, the code is completely different from what the question is (Homes and Apartments vs. Boats and Sail Sizes).  Anyway, to more directly answer the question, what is the code for "Apartment.GetAddress()"?  If you truly want to dump the entire address into one column of a ListBox (vs. multiple columns in a ListView, like in my answer), then the issue is in your string formatting in Apartment.GetAddress().  Most likely you are including a CR, LF, or both.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that you want to display multiple columns of data in the ListBox, then you should consider switching to a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You would then add the other column values by using code similar to this:

Add a **ListView** control to your form.

A am assuming you have 4 text boxes named **txtBoatName**, **txtLength**, **txtSailSize**, **txtEngines**

```
// You can either set the columns and view in code like below, or use
// the Form designer in Visual Studio to set them.  If you set them in code,
// place the following in Form.Load

listView1.View = View.Details;

listView1.Columns.Add("Boat Name", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Length", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Sail Size", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Engines", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Center);

// When you want to add a boat to the ListView, use code like the following:

ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(txtBoatName.Text,0);
item1.SubItems.Add(txtLength.Text);
item1.SubItems.Add(txtSailSize.Text);
item1.SubItems.Add(txtEngines.Text);

listView1.Items.Add(item1);
```